# Nginx allows file download even with error 403 forbidden

Tags: centos, nginx

I have setup a new centos 7. 
I have installed 
yum install php72u-fpm
yum install nginx -y

Next I did was to change the root folder in the config file in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. to /var/www/html.

```
server_name  _;
        root         /var/www/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

Next I created a new folder /var/www/html/test
and I gave nginx the permission chown -R nginx.nginx /var/www/html/test/
So then I got to my http://*.*.*.*/test/ I get 403 forbidden and I check the error log what I get is this.

```
2018/04/11 14:43:47 [error] 24229#0: *10 directory index of "/var/www/html/test/" is forbidden, client: *.*.*.*, server: _, request: "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1", host: "*.*.*.*"
```

But to my surprise when I run this command for e.g. http://*.*.*.*/test/page1.php it gets download to my local machine this is definitely a security issue right? How to block this from happening?

Comment: Do you want to protect all of the files in the `test` directory or all files with a `.php` extension?

Comment: I want to protect all the files just like apache? Can that be done ?